# Vuetify v-combobox huge items list rendering

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using vuetify v3.

In my use case, I have a multiple lists with different sizes (the big one can reach  ~100k items) that I want to render in multiple `v-combobox`, I've tried this code :

```
<v-col v-for="property in filterableProperties">
  <v-combobox v-model="filter[property.code]" :label="property.label" :items="values[property.code]" 
              variant="outlined" hide-details bg-color="white" clearable/>
</v-col>
```

`values` is an objet containing those lists.

My issue is that browser freeze when clicking on the `v-combobox` containing the huge list. I don't need to display all 100k items in a time, a lazy loading will do just fine. I haven't find a way to do that.

Any help ?

Comment: virtual-scroll is not in v3 atm:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/15585

Comment: Okay thank you @xyos I'll wait for v3.1